# Puppeteer code works locally but throws "Navigation timeout exceeded" on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, amazon-ec2, proxy, puppeteer

I have a Node.js application that uses Puppeteer for web scraping. The following code snippet works perfectly fine on my local machine, but when I deploy the application to an AWS EC2 instance, it fails to work. I'm trying to take a screenshot of a webpage using Puppeteer, but it doesn't seem to be working on the EC2 instance.

I'm getting below error

```
An error occurred while running Puppeteer: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
```

Below code

```
  app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
        try {
          console.log('Launching Puppeteer...');
          const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
          console.log('Puppeteer launched successfully.');
      
          console.log('Creating a new page...');
          const page = await browser.newPage();
          console.log('New page created.');
      
          console.log('Navigating to https://xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.xx/xxxxx-xxxxx ....');
          await page.goto('https://xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.xx/xxxxx-xxxxx');
          console.log('Navigation completed.');
      
          console.log('Taking a screenshot...');
          await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
          console.log('Screenshot captured.');
      
          console.log('Closing Puppeteer...');
          await browser.close();
          console.log('Puppeteer closed.');
      
          console.log('Sending a success response.');
          res.send('Puppeteer is working fine! Check the screenshot.');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('An error occurred while running Puppeteer:', error);
          res.status(500).send('Error occurred while running Puppeteer.');
        }
      });
```

Outbound rules Info

```
Security group rule ID  Type        Protocol    Port range  Destination Description - optional
sgr-03a3df4cd58d4b300   Custome TCP TCP         8080        None        found   0.0.0.0/0   
sgr-0b3fc010cab96b837   All Trafic  All         All         None        found   0.0.0.0/0   
sgr-017090ccbaec3ec41   HTTPS       TCP         443         None        found   0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 2):

This timeout error may be originating from either:

- The target website has a firewall that blocks the traffic that originates from:

  - Known public IP addresses used in the Cloud.
  - Known browsers used for scrapping such as Chromium
- A less likely source of problem is that your EC2 instance could not connect to the internet. Are you sure that this browser could reach the internet? Have you tried to visit other webpages to test out connectivity to other websites? Have you tried to issue a CURl command to request the home page of your target website inside the EC2 instance? If you can rule out this connectivity issue, then its more likely an issue related to the IP-filtering implemented by the website's firewall.

You can solve this challenge by directing your puppeteer instance to use proxies to connect to the target site. You can try to use [private proxies](https://privateproxy.me) to check if it works.

```js
const proxyList = [
    'http://skrll:au4....',
    ' http://skrll:au4....',
    ' http://skrll:au4....',
    ' http://skrll:au4....',
    ' http://skrll:au4....',
];
    
    const oldProxyUrl = proxyList[Math.floor(Math.random() * (proxiesList.length))];
    const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            args: [
              `--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`,
              `--ignore-certificate-errors`,
              `--no-sandbox`,
              `--disable-setuid-sandbox`
            ]
     });
```